# Mic/Speakers Audio Feedback in VLC API

Tags: c++, qt, echo-cancellation, vlc-qt

I'm building a Webcam recording application with Qt 5.3 using [vlc-qt](http://projects.tano.si/vlc-qt/), the problem is while previewing Audio/Video high feedback/noise and echo starts and gets higher, I've been googling and found it's the effect called Larsen's effect and how it's happening.

Notes:

- I know using a headphone is a solution
- I'm on a Windows 7 Ultimate Notebook
- The Microphone Boost on zero dB is less noise but echo is persistent

My Questions:

- How other webcam recording applications suppress the noise and the echo?
- Specifically, how it can be fixed in VLC, your answer can be commandline arguments, notes or instructions to do in VLC software, it doesn't have to be code

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found http://www.dspcottage.com/en/algorithms/AEC a C++/MFC echo cancellation application based on Speex, but I needed to use it in Qt so I scrapped all MFC related code and here is the final solution https://github.com/Marware/Cpp_AEC